JupyterLab — multiple projects on local machine
I have on my local machine multiple independent projects and I'd like to have an easy way to switch between them in Jupyter Lab. In each of them I'd like to have a separate workspace for easier context switching in my mind. Using Jupyter Lab inside a code editor (like VSCode or PyCharm) is not an option for me.
Paths are quite arbitrary and usually have a long structure which looks like category/subcategory/project/some-folder with a common prefix. In my shell (zsh) I access them using dir aliases by cd ~-project-a, so I don't need to remember paths.
I've already separated workspaces using environment variable JUPYTERLAB_WORKSPACES_DIR, so workspaces aren't a problem.
For a proxy I prefer to use nginx, for python and virtual environment I prefer to use pip or uv (no conda as I don't see any major improvements above those two)
I prefer not to run NodeJS as it consumes quite a lot of resources thus my battery life on notebook and electricity for homelab server.
I'd like to have any ideas to
